# How can I reset a form field and show Success or Thanks you after form submission?

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

I have a simple email subscription form on a landing page that I managed to get working to save emails in a google sheet spreadsheet. I followed this post https://github.com/jamiewilson/form-to-google-sheets

The problem is nothing happens to indicate a successful submission. Looking for a solution to reset the field and potentially a Thank you message without leaving the page.

My Code:

```html
<section>
  <form name="submit-to-google-sheet">
    <div class="jr_notified_form">
      <div class="jr_form_email">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Name@company.com">
      </div>
      <div class="jr_form_submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Get Notified">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form> 
</section>
<!-- notified area end -->

<!-- Google Sheet Script Area -->     
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/formdata-polyfill"></script>
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/promise-polyfill@latest"></script>
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/whatwg-fetch@latest"></script>
<script>
  const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxcnv-svFYW-mhUmyzs_FhtXFWg96hOiDiD8vanzv08766Wr0/exec'
  const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']

  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
      .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
      
  })

</script>
```

Someone suggested this (didn't work):

```js
    form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
    .then(response => console.log('Success!', response), location = "yourpagehere.com)
    .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
    })
```

And someone suggested this (also didn't work):

```js
    form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
    .then(response => { console.log('Success!', response); window.location.href="thanks.html";} )
    .catch(error => { console.error('Error!', error.message); window.location.href="error.html";} )
    })
```

`form.reset()` and `form.fireEvent("reset");` where also suggested but i couldnt figure out how to properly implement either of them

Comment: _“And someone suggested this (also didnt work)”_ - and [ask] suggests giving us actual proper problem descriptions, instead of “doesn’t work”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a function that clears input field and displays a "success message" after a successful POST.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form name="submit-to-google-sheet">
    <!-- Add success message and make its display to "none" -->
    <span id="successMessage" style="display: none; color: green">POST successful!</span>
                <div class="jr_notified_form">
                  <div class="jr_form_email">
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Name@company.com">
                  </div>
                  <div class="jr_form_submit">
                    <input type="submit" value="Get Notified">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
</body>
<!-- Google Sheet Script Area -->     
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/formdata-polyfill"></script>
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/promise-polyfill@latest"></script>
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/whatwg-fetch@latest"></script>
<script>
  const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxcnv-svFYW-mhUmyzs_FhtXFWg96hOiDiD8vanzvziGzigaWr0/exec'
  const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']

  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
      .then(response => console.log('Success!', success()))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
      
  })

  function success(){
        //Clear form input
        document.querySelectorAll('input')[0].value = '';
        //Display success message
        document.getElementById('successMessage').style.display = 'block';
  }
 </script>      
</html>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks so much, I had to mess around with the <div>s cause my site actually had more than I posted around the form, but figured it out....this did the trick!!!!!!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!